# New to Prolog, Lists and Pairs

Tags: list, prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding how some of the mechanics actually works. Right now I'm trying to work on a particular problem.

I need to find all possible pairs from a single list and so I'm trying to define rules select_pairs(X,Y,_,Z).

Below is what I expect to see when I run the given queries.

The query: select_pairs(X,Y,[1,2,3],Z). returns the following:

```
X = 1, Y = 2, Zs = [3] ;
X = 1, Y = 3, Zs = [2] ;
X = 2, Y = 1, Zs = [3] ;
X = 2, Y = 3, Zs = [1] ;
X = 3, Y = 1, Zs = [2] ;
X = 3, Y = 2, Zs = [3]
```

AND the query select_pairs(1,2,Xs,[3]). returns the following:

```
Xs = [1, 2, 3] ;
Xs = [2, 1, 3] ;
Xs = [1, 3, 2] ;
Xs = [2, 3, 1] ;
Xs = [3, 1, 2] ;
Xs = [3, 2, 1] ;
```

As of right now, I can only get the first result from the first query to show up and nothing more. What's the best way from me to approach this? Thank you!

Comment: It is unclear to me: have _you_ defined the predicate `select_pairs/4`? How is it defined? Is the listing you are showing something you see on your screen or something you are expecting to see?

Comment: Sorry I should clarify that... I need to define select_pairs. I have a partial definition, but it only returns a small portion of what I expect to get.
Both listings above show what I'm expecting to see when it runs properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your Prolog should come with [select](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=select/3)/3, a builtin that's doing exactly what's suggested by its name:

```
?- select(X,[1,2,3],R).
X = 1,
R = [2, 3] ;
X = 2,
R = [1, 3] ;
X = 3,
R = [1, 2] ;
false.
```

it also works 'backwards'

```
?- select(1,R,[2,3]).
R = [1, 2, 3] ;
R = [2, 1, 3] ;
R = [2, 3, 1] ;
false.
```

Then, to get a working select_pairs/4, you could just combine 2 select/3.

Comment: Okay thanks, but it still doesn't print ALL the possible pairs. I'm only getting one instance. Any thoughts as to why that might be?

So instead of getting say:
R = [1, 2, 3] ;
R = [2, 1, 3] ;
R = [2, 3, 1] ;

I'm only getting 
R = [1, 2, 3] ; back.

Comment: Did you write down select_pairs using 2 select ? If you want to display all solutions, use forall/2

Comment: Yes I used 2 select. I'm not sure I understand how the forall predicate works.